# Cache Notification config not working in Windows Azure Cache Preview

Tags: c#, azure, azure-caching

I'm trying to set up a Windows Azure Cache Preview implementation, but I'm running into problems getting the local cache configuration to work. Here is my current config:

```
<dataCacheClients>
  <tracing sinkType="DiagnosticSink" traceLevel="Error" />
  <dataCacheClient name="default" requestTimeout="30000" 
                   maxConnectionsToServer="5" isCompressionEnabled="true">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="{My Role Name}" />
        <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="NotificationBased" 
                    objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />
        <clientNotification pollInterval="60" />
  </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

I create the default cache object using Ninject, like this:

```
Bind<DataCache>().ToMethod((context) => new DataCacheFactory().GetDefaultCache());
```

This injection worked fine when I wasn't doing anything with local caching, but I ran into problems putting large data sets into the cache (timeouts), so I figured I would see what behavior would result from using the local cache.

Since I changed the configuration (based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh916611.aspx#section_3) on MSDN, see "Caching (Preview) on Roles" in that section), I get the following error:

> ErrorCode ERRCA0015:SubStatus ES0001:Notification-based invalidation
> is not supported because the Cache is not configured to support
> Notifications.

That is a bit confusing, since I thought that was what the dataCacheClients config section was supposed to be doing. Do I need to programatically set something on the DataCache object itself, or am I missing something in the web config?

Comment: By the way, reviewers, would it make sense to create the tag azure-cache-preview? I would but I don't quite have the rep to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the named cache on the server side has notifications enabled. This can be looked at in the Visual Studio under the 'Caching' Tab for the Azure Role which has Cache server side on it.